# Json + Jsoup распарсить

Tags: java, json, jsoup

При обрашение к сайту получаем json объект

```
{
userId: 32,
firstName: "Алексей",
lastName: "Голобурдин",
address: {
country: "Россия",
city: "Москва"
},
phone: "8 (905) 777 77 77"
}
```

как его распарсить с помощью jsoup

```
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
obj = Jsoup.connect(URL).ignoreContentType(true).execute().body();
```

выдает ошибку.

Comment: С помощью jsoup - никак. Ищите парсер json.

Comment: какую выдает ошибку?

Comment: error: variable obj is already defined in method doInBackground(Void...)

Comment: @АндрейКрузлик, переименуйте obj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строка:

```
obj = Jsoup.connect(URL).ignoreContentType(true).execute().body();
```

даже не скомпилируется, так как `.body()` возвращает `String`, а левая часть имеет тип `JSONObject`

У `JSONObject` (из пакета org.json) есть конструктор, принимающий `String`:

```
String jsonString = Jsoup.connect(URL).ignoreContentType(true).execute().body();
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```